# How to adapt UV code to use a tilesheet that is "uneven"?

Tags: c#, unity, uv-mapping

The tutorial has code that takes a tilesheet and builds a UV mapping:

```
 const float tileSize = 0.25f;

 public virtual Vector2[] FaceUVs(Direction direction)
 {
     Vector2[] UVs = new Vector2[4];
     Tile tilePos = TexturePosition(direction);

     UVs[0] = new Vector2(tileSize * tilePos.x + tileSize,
         tileSize * tilePos.y);
     UVs[1] = new Vector2(tileSize * tilePos.x + tileSize,
         tileSize * tilePos.y + tileSize);
     UVs[2] = new Vector2(tileSize * tilePos.x,
         tileSize * tilePos.y + tileSize);
     UVs[3] = new Vector2(tileSize * tilePos.x,
         tileSize * tilePos.y);

     return UVs;
 }
```

He explains why he uses `tileSize = 0.25f`:

> The variable tileSize is equal to 1 divided by the number of tiles per
>   side, in the case of our example texture 1/4 (0.25). The function
>   creates an array of vector2 and gets the tile position with the
>   direction and populates the array based on the tile position. Every UV
>   coordinate corresponds to a vertex and the triangle made of those
>   vertices uses the corresponding texture coordinates.

This is the tilesheet he is using, which is a 4x4:

[image]

I have a tilesheet which is not a 4x4:

[image]

I have tried `tileSize = 0.0667f` (1/15 if I assume the tilesheet is 15x15), but this is not correct. For example, a grass block is (5, 14) for the side, and (5, 8) for the top. But the game renders really weird textures.

**What should the** `tileSize` **be since this tilesheet is not a perfect square** (it looks like 6x15 tiles, but it also has a lot of empty space which might cause problems)?

---

Reference:

Tutorial:
`http://alexstv.com/index.php/posts/unity-voxel-block-tutorial-pt-2`

Source tilesheet (CC0 license):
`http://kenney.nl/assets/voxel-pack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have had an issue with your tile-sheet. The question now displays a properly framed one.

It looks like at 6*15 tile sheet. So...

Instead of using a `float tileSize`, which has the same value for the x and the y axis, I would suggest you use a vector2 instead:

```
// Keep in mind that my c# is not good so you may need to adjust the syntax of the code, but
// it gives you an idea. 
const Vector2 tileSize(1/6, 1/15); // This is to be used with the current texture

public virtual Vector2[] FaceUVs(Direction direction)
{
  Vector2[] UVs = new Vector2[4];
  Tile tilePos = TexturePosition(direction);

  UVs[0] = new Vector2(tileSize.x * tilePos.x + tileSize.x, tileSize.y * tilePos.y);
  UVs[1] = new Vector2(tileSize.x * tilePos.x + tileSize.x, tileSize.y * tilePos.y + tileSize.y);
  UVs[2] = new Vector2(tileSize.x * tilePos.x, tileSize.y * tilePos.y + tileSize.y);
  UVs[3] = new Vector2(tileSize.x * tilePos.x, tileSize.y * tilePos.y);

  return UVs;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the `tileSize`? Unity is also throwing errors on that line `The type Vector2 cannot be declared const`

Comment: maybe it's better to split it to two variables: `tileSizeX = 1/6f` and `tileSizeY = 1/15f` or something like that? Then would the UVs be `UVs[2] = new Vector2(tileSizeX * tilePos.x, tileSizeY * tilePos.y + tileSizeY);`

Comment: @meepboop It's not better, it's just a different way to achieve the same thing. If it works for you, that's great! The `tileSize` can be viewed as `tile ratio of the image`. In your case, it's not the same in x an in y, so this is why you need two. And if Unity throws an error, you should say what it is and where it's coming from.

Comment: Okay, I tried it out and it looks like your fix to the spritesheet and with splitting the `tileSize` into two variables, it now works! Thanks!

Comment: I'm very new to c#, so my naive thinking was to split the ratio you specified for `tileSize` into two variables since Unity was complaining about `Vector2 cannot be declared const`. Is there a more elegant way to that workaround?

Comment: You could probably not declare it as const, but put it as a class attribute of your GameObject, and initialize it there. At this point it depends on your architecture. And tbh, the vector is fancy, if the 2 variables float your boat, I don't think anyone will complain about it :)